# How to check if email exist with bookshelf and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have been trying to check if email exist with bookshelfjs, but I always get empty response each time. If I try other fields it works perfectly.

( **I prefer if this could work**, is there something I am doing wrong?)

```
var useremail = await Customer.where({ 'email': req.body.email }).fetch({ require: true });
```

But if I do this I get the right response.

```
var username = await Customer.where({ 'name': req.body.name }).fetch({ require: true });
```

I tried this too. fetched all users, then try to get the email, then check if req.body.email exist. but still didnt work

```
        var emails = await Customer.fetchAll().then(users => {
            users.forEach(element => {
                var emailAlone = element.attributes.email;
                for (const item in emailAlone) {
                    if (item == req.body.email) {
                    console.log("Item is ", item);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed like this

For those might what to do it like this. 
If there is a better way someone should suggest

```
      await Customer.where({ 'email': req.body.email }).fetch({ require: true }).then(
            users => {
                if (users.attributes.email.length > 0) {
                    return res.status(500).json(
                        { error: true, message: "email already exist" }
                    );
                }
                else {
                    console.log("registering now");
                   }
```

I still to see how to check both email and username

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more of a beginner style but it works fine (might run slower on big sets of data).

```
async function createBookshelfOf(tbl){ // Helper function
    return bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: tbl,
        idAttribute: "id"
    });
}

app.post("/register",async(req, res) => {
    try{

        let bookshelfCustomers = await createBookshelfOf("Customers");
        let Customers = await new bookshelfCustomers().fetchAll();

        for (let customer of Customers.toJSON()){
            if (customer.email === req.body.email){
                res.status(403).send("Customer with this email exists");
            }
        }
        // If customer doesn't exist code below will execute

        {your code}
                
        res.status(200).send("Successfully perforned ...")
   

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        res.status(500).send(e.message);

    }

});
```